# Writing a table with a lot of entries

Tags: tables

I have 21 pairs of experimental data. I want to present into a standarized form. My work so far is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{||r||r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
$V_p$ / mV               & 202 & 225 & 250 & 275 & 301 & 325 & 349 & 375 & 400 & 424 & 450  \\ \hline
$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$ / mV & 434 & 486 & 540 & 593 & 652 & 703 & 757 & 812 & 867 & 917 & 973 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{||r||r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
$V_p$/mV               & 474  & 500  & 525  & 550  & 574  & 600  & 626  & 650  & 674  & 699  \\ \hline
$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$ / mV &  1025 & 1081 & 1137 & 1190 & 1242 & 1298 & 1356 & 1409 & 1474 & 1531 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experimental values for ...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

but it doesn't look good.. how may I handle tables this large?

Comment: Do you want the result to still be in a horizontal table? Or would a vertical orientation also be suitable (i.e. all the pairs of data in new rows instead of columns)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A vertical orientation may also be nice, as long as it is optimized to leave not too much blank space

Comment: please always post full document not just a fragment, so we can see the result. inital comments don't use `[h]` and numeric columns are better `r` or using a specific numeric alignment such as dcolumn or siunitx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use three pairs of columns, with a dummy column between pairs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  c
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  c
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]
}
\toprule
{$V_p$} & {$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$} &&
{$V_p$} & {$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$} &&
{$V_p$} & {$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
202 & 434 && 375 &  812 && 550 & 1190 \\
225 & 486 && 400 &  867 && 574 & 1242 \\
250 & 540 && 424 &  917 && 600 & 1298 \\
275 & 593 && 450 &  973 && 626 & 1356 \\
301 & 652 && 474 & 1025 && 650 & 1409 \\
325 & 703 && 500 & 1081 && 674 & 1474 \\
349 & 757 && 525 & 1137 && 699 & 1531 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\footnotesize Values in \si{mV}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experimental values for ...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer because it is the one that makes less repetition (Values in mV, good one, silly me...) and looks very nice. Thanks. However may you explain a little bit the code? I'm not familiar with those packages.

Comment: @Jorge Explaining `siunitx` needs a whole manual. `;-)` Look around in the site for it and you'll find several examples. Also, read the beginning of the documentation for `booktabs` (for instance [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)) and you'll fall in love with `\toprule` and friends.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{table}
\centering
\addtolength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\boldmath}l*{7}r@{}}
\toprule
$V_p$/mV          & 202 & 225 & 250 & 275 & 301 & 325 & 349 \\
 $E_{\mathrm{ef}}$/mV & 434 & 486 & 540 & 593 & 652 & 703 & 757 \\
\midrule
$V_p$/mV        & 375 & 400 & 424 & 450  & 474  & 500  & 525 \\
$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$/mV& 812 & 867 & 917 & 973 &  1025 & 1081 & 1137 \\
\midrule
$V_p$/mV        & 550  & 574  & 600  & 626  & 650  & 674  & 699  \\
$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$/mV  & 1190 & 1242 & 1298 & 1356 & 1409 & 1474 & 1531 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experimental values for ...}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `hhline` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes[t]{3pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\doublerulesep{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{||l|@{}c@{\,\,}|*{10}{r|}r||}%
\hhline{-|~|----------~}\noalign{\vskip-0.4pt}\cline{13-13}
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{$V_p$ / mV} & & 202 & 225 & 250 & 275 & 301 & 325 & 349 & 375 & 400 & 424 & 450 \\
\hhline{||-|~|-----------||}
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$ / mV} & & 434 & 486 & 540 & 593 & 652 & 703 & 757 & 812 & 867 & 917 & 973 \\
\cline{13-13}\hhline{|:=:~:==========}
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{$V_p$/mV} & & 474 & 500 & 525 & 550 & 574 & 600 & 626 & 650 & 674 & \multicolumn{1}{r||}{699} \\
\hhline{||-||~|----------||}
\multicolumn{1}{||l|}{$E_{\mathrm{ef}}$ / mV} & & 1025 & 1081 & 1137 & 1190 & 1242 & 1298 & 1356 & 1409 & 1474 & \multicolumn{1}{r||}{1531} \\
\hhline{-|~|---------}\cline{12-12}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Experimental values for ...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]